# Case sensitive path comparison in python

Tags: python, macos, path, comparison, case-sensitive

I have to check whether a file is present a particular path in Mac OS X.

There is a file called foo.F90 inside the directory.

But when I do `if(os.path.exists(PATH_TO_foo.f90))`, it returns true and does not notice that f90 is lower case and the file which exists is upper case F90.

I tried `open(PATH_TO_foo.f90, "r")`, even this does not work

How do I get around this?

Comment: Are you dealing with a case-sensitive file system?

Comment: Could you paste the actual error message you get? I just tried this on WinXP and it seems to work fine.

Comment: I am running it on a Mac OSX. So, I think it is case insensitive. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am not getting any error. But I want to perform case sensitive file name comparison. In this case, I want it to return False when I try with lower case extension as such a file is not there.

Comment: If the file system you're working on is not case sensitive, then it will not care when you go to access the files. If you still want to do a true comparison, you can compare the string literals of the paths rather than using `os.path.exists`.

Comment: I actually want to find out if such a file exists.

Comment: The filesystem on OS X is case-preserving, but not case-sensitive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As some commenters have noted, Python doesn't really care about case in paths on case-insensitive filesystems, so none of the path comparison or manipulation functions will really do what you need.

However, you can indirectly test this with `os.listdir()`, which does give you the directory contents with their actual cases.  Given that, you can test if the file exists with something like:

```
'foo.f90' in os.listdir('PATH_TO_DIRECTORY')
```

Comment: This would not work if there is a nesting of folders and the sensitivity needs to be checked at each level, as the case mismatch could be in the parent of the directory of file direcotry. In that case, the above mentioned check needs to be applied at each level of folder nesting

Answer (score 1):

This is something related to your underlying Operating system and not python. For example, in windows the filesystem is case-insensitive while in Linux it is case sensitive. So if I run the same check, as you are running, on a linux based system I won't get true for case insensitive matches -

```
>>> os.path.exists('F90')
True
>>> os.path.exists('f90')
False                      # on my linux based OS
```

Still if you really want to get a solution around this, you can do this -

```
if 'f90' in os.listdir(os.path.dirname('PATH_TO_foo.f90')):
    # do whatever you want to do
```

Comment: Python in Mac OS X is case insensitive if you use `os.path.exists`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still struggling with this. The following snippet works for me.

```py
from pathlib import Path

def path_exists_case_sensitive(p: Path) -> bool:
    """Check if path exists, enforce case sensitivity.

    Arguments:
      p: Path to check
    Returns:
      Boolean indicating if the path exists or not
    """
    # If it doesn't exist initially, return False
    if not p.exists():
        return False

    # Else loop over the path, checking each consecutive folder for
    # case sensitivity
    while True:
        # At root, p == p.parent --> break loop and return True
        if p == p.parent:
            return True
        # If string representation of path is not in parent directory, return False
        if str(p) not in map(str, p.parent.iterdir()):
            return False
        p = p.parent
```

Answer (score 0):

If the path changes between systems or something you could use:

```
import os, fnmatch

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'foo.*'):
        print file
```

This will return all files foo.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you -

```
    import os  

    def exists(path):  
        import win32api  
        if path.find('/') != -1:  
            msg = 'Invalid path for Windows %s'%path  
            raise Exception(msg)  
        path = path.rstrip(os.sep)  
        try:  
            fullpath = win32api.GetLongPathNameW(win32api.GetShortPathName(path))  
        except Exception, fault:  
            return False  
        if fullpath == path:  
            return True  
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score -1):

So, since you do not have a case sensitive filesystem, how about

```
import os
if 'foo.F90' in os.listdir(PATH_TO_DIRECTORY):
    open(PATH_TO_DIRECTORY + 'foo.F90')
```

Comment: Does not work, it's still case sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

Easy way to do this for Python 3.5+ using `pathlib`. Works for files and dirs:

```
from pathlib import Path

def exists_case_sensitive(path) -> bool:
    p = Path(path)
    if not p.exists():
        # If it already doesn't exist(), 
        # we can skip iterdir().
        return False
    return p in p.parent.iterdir()
```